# Joi Validator must valid at least given value, but other will also allowed

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, joi

```
 Joi.object().keys({
              myObject: Joi.array().items(Joi.object().keys({
                key: Joi.string().valid('fristName','lastName'),
                value: Joi.any().required(),
              })),
            });
```

Here I want must required 'firstName' and 'lastName' but other will also allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your context, but i think thats it should help you.
[.unknown() method](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v9.0.4/API.md#objectunknownallow)

Comment: unknown is useful on keys, but I need validation on values

Answer (score 0):

You can otherwise with validation refer otherwise api to solve it.